# Control brightness of a Dell Ultrasharp monitor

Tags: brightness, monitor

I have a Dell U3419W monitor plugged to a Lenovo T440p laptop running Ubuntu 18.04. Using the Ubuntu brightness controls (slider, keys) when using the Dell Monitor has no effect. The Windows Dell utility is able to change the brightness via software, so the monitor supports it.

Is there any chance of this working in Ubuntu?

Thanks